# Laravel: Remove jobs from queue

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, jobs, horizon

Is there a way to remove all jobs from a queue.
We use Laravel Horizon to monitor it. We recognised that there are way to many jobs running in the queue.

Comment: It's not in the core framework, so you'll need to do this manually or write your own scripts to do it. There are packages like [this one](https://github.com/JeffcottLu/laravel-clear) that can automate the process for you.

Comment: Are data in the queue jobs critical? If not just `FLUSHDB` the redis database.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do this, but depending on the driver you use you can remove them manually.

I am using the database driver and I often remove queued items if there are to many or one is stuck. In my project I have created a database model for jobs to do this.